# java stream groupingBy with EnumMap or other?

Tags: java, java-stream

Which version should I prefer in terms of *fastest* and *lowest memory*?

**version 1:**

```
public Map<TYPE, List<Task>> getTaskByType() {
    return tasks.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Task::getType, 
                     () -> new EnumMap<>(TYPE.class), 
                     Collectors.toList()));
    }
```

**version 2:**

```
public Map<TYPE, List<Task>> getTaskByType() {
    return tasks.stream().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Task::getType));
}
```

or another version?

**Edit:**

If you have a lots of Enums then use **version 1!**

Comment: you should really not care about this here - unless you profile and see an actual problem. I would use the second as it is a lot easier to read IMO

Comment: @Eugene but I care about this and as I already have an Enum for grouping, why not looking for best practice?

Comment: the best practice is _usually_ anything that is easier to read; in most cases at least

Comment: dont want to debate what is easier to read..we know version 2 is easier to read..but how about memory consumption and performance. I guess, version 1 is better because of EnumMap-Impl.

Comment: In about 99% of cases I'd use version 2, simply because it's easier to read (that's a personal opinion I guess). Something like that should be one of the last things to optimize - most likely the JVM would optimize it anyway.

Comment: Why downvote? Does anyone knows or argued before that the versions are identical? I think it's good to know for other people also. Shorter not always means better. Shorter is not always best practice, reason about this.

Comment: Your question is answered by the javadoc of EnumMap: *This representation is extremely compact and efficient. * [...] *All basic operations execute in constant time. They are likely (though not guaranteed) to be faster than their HashMap counterparts.*. When you wonder if EnumMap is more compact and afficient than HashMap, why don't you read the documentation of EnumMap? But again, the chance of this having any significant impact on the performance or memory consumption of your app is very low.

Comment: @JBNizet I know that about EnumMap, however, if you read the answer below, it does not matter which implementation, because it all results in the same.

Comment: No, the result is not the same. One produces a HashMap, the other produces an EnumMap.

Comment: @JBNizet ok, thanks. Then I am right with my assuption and I will use the longer but better "version 1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second snippet produces a HashMap (although that's a non-guaranteed implementation detail).

So your question is answered by the [javadoc of EnumMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html):

> This representation is extremely compact and efficient. [...] All basic operations execute in constant time. They are likely (though not guaranteed) to be faster than their HashMap counterparts.

But I agree with every other commenter: the chance of this having any significant impact on the performance or memory consumption of your app is very low, and you should favor readability rather than micro-optimizations than decrease it.

Comment: I dont agree with your opinion and the other commenter. There is an objective reason to use EnumMap over HashSet as described in the javadoc. Downvoting  my question does not make it right.